# Vuetify remove pagination on v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, pagination, vuetify.js

I want remove pagination on v-data-table, I tried to use `hide-default-footer` but it doesn't work.

```html
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="desserts"
  hide-default-header
  hide-default-footer
  class="elevation-1"
>
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <td>{{ props.index }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ getProject(props.item.project_uuid) }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.deadline }}</td>
        <td>{{ getUser(props.item.executor) }}</td>
        <td>{{ getUser(props.item.creator) }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.description }}</td>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It should be `:hide-default-footer="true"`

```html
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="desserts"
  :hide-default-header="true"
  :hide-default-footer="true"
  class="elevation-1"
>
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <td>{{ props.index }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ getProject(props.item.project_uuid) }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.deadline }}</td>
        <td>{{ getUser(props.item.executor) }}</td>
        <td>{{ getUser(props.item.creator) }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.description }}</td>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Demo on [codepen](https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/PMEeoz)

Comment: In case someone finds this later, the slot is "item" not "items" and you have to supply the <tr> tag as well.

Comment: See idirsun comment, if you only do that you will only see the first 10 elements.

Comment: For Vuetify 2.x: This only hides the pagination controls, but the table still paginates. You need to hide the controls as well as disable the actual pagination of the results for the latest versions.

Comment: Very important: set disable-pagination also, otherwise as mentioned above you will only see 10 elements.

Comment: You can also just use `hide-default-footer` instead of `:hide-default-footer="true"`

Comment: hiding the footer does not disable paging. when there are more than 10 data items/desserts they will not be shown in the table and users can access them (expect you add paging functionality to your custom footer). so you also need to add :disable-pagination="true" to show all data in the table as mentioned by @idirsun

Answer (score 27):

adding 
`:hide-default-header="true"`
`:hide-default-footer="true"`
will only remove the default footer and header, 
to completely disable pagination you need to add 
`disable-pagination` to your `<v-data-table>`

Comment: From what i have experienced you need both

Comment: Likewise just `disable-pagination` is not enough, it will bug out the footer which is still interactible but doesnt do anything. There is also middleground of `items-per-page="-1"` + footer props to limit it to all. That way most of the footer will be hidden and just item counter remains.

Answer (score 13):

I just add these two props to `v-data-table`

```html
<v-data-table hide-default-footer disable-pagination />
```

No need to assign `true` to the props .i.e `hide-default-footer="true"`

That's what I usually do.

Comment: Do you know if there's any tricky on this when using VueJs 3.2 and Vite 3.2.4? Because I've tried these options but my footer never goes away.

Comment: What version of Vuetify are you using? If you use Vuetify 3, then the above approach is obsolete. It works with Vuetify 2 only

Answer (score 13):

For those arriving here using Vuetify 3, I've found adding an empty footer slot achieves the same:

```html
<template #bottom></template>
```

To show more than the first 10 items, disable pagination with         `:items-per-page="0"`. Full example:

```html
<v-data-table
    :items="thedata"
    :items-per-page="0"
  >
  <template #bottom></template>
</v-data-table>
```

Here's further documentation on the footer slot:

- https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/slots/
- https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#slots-bottom

Answer (score 10):

The correct answer for this is adding the attribute `disable-pagination` as it's stated on Vuetify documentation: 
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/
[Vuetify documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlnRI.png)

This is true for Vuetify 2.x version, if you're using Vuetify 1.5 use the `hide-actions`attribute instead. 
https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables

Comment: This turns off pagination, and the whole item list will display. This does not hide the pagination footer however

Answer (score 6):

to disable pagination on v-data-table use **disable-pagination** prop[image]

Comment: In addition to posting a screenshot of the documentation add the relevant link as it is easier to find more information that way.

Comment: Not sure why but this prop has no effect.

Comment: It's for vue2, but for vue3 need to use templates

Answer (score 0):

In Vuetify 3, you can use the #bottom slot to customize the bottom section of the v-data-table, including the pagination controls. Here's how you can hide the pagination controls using the #bottom slot.

For Vuetify 3.5.3 my solution is

```
<v-data-table :items="item.req_skills" :items-per-page="-1">
  <template #bottom>
    <!-- Leave this slot empty to hide pagination controls -->
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Answer (score -4):

The answer from ittus almost works, but the attributes should not be bound (unless you have a data property called "true" that is set to a boolean of true.

Instead,

```
:hide-default-header="true"
:hide-default-footer="true"
```

should be

```
hide-default-header="true"
hide-default-footer="true"
```

Comment: This is in fact wrong. Doing it this way passes the string "true" as a prop, which can cause vue warnings for receiving a data type it does not expect. Instead, simply provide the attribute without a value (eg, just `hide-default-footer`).